# Gaining the same Natural Attacks from multiple sources

Tags: pathfinder-1e, natural-weapon, stacking

There are multiple sources from which you can gain natural attacks (Bloodlines, Rage Powers, Racial Features etc.)
What happens when you gain, say, a Bite Attack from being a [Half-Orc](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/half-orc/) with the "Toothy" Racial trait and a Barbarian with the [Animal Fury](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo-rage-powers/animal-fury-ex) Rage Power?

Does it stack somehow?